# Is there any example of two surface having same first fubndamental form are whose second fundamental form are different.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

I know that two surfaces are isometric if and only if they have same first fundamental form. I can not think of any examples of two surfaces in $R^3$ which have the same first fundamental form but different second fundamental form.  Is there an example of two surfaces with this property?

Thank you.

Comment: Why surfaces : already plane curve, two curves are locally isometric, but they have the same curvature iff they are the same up to an isometry of the plane. A line (0 curvature) and a circle (of radious r, curvaturee r^2) are locally isometric !

Comment: I am a newly joined Research Scholar. My field of research is Curve and Surface. I want to do something on Isometry, First and Second Fundamental form, Gaussian Curvature. If you suggest some books or article I will be very helpful. Or plz give me some suggestion how to go ahed with this topic.

Comment: Manfredo Do Carmo, Differential geometry of curves and surfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Please don't edit three-year-old posts unless you're making a substantial mathematical improvement. It brings them up to the front of the line and for absolutely no good reason.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, excuse me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the cylinder $\mathbb{x}(u,v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$. They have the same first fundamental form given by: $E=G=1,F=0$. But the second fundamental form of a cylinder is: $L=<U,\mathbb{x}_{uu}>=-1 \neq 0$.